Git Action with Docker do not find .jar file
# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.
# This workflow will build a Java project with Gradle and cache/restore any dependencies to improve the workflow execution time
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-java-with-gradle

name: Java CI with Gradle with Docker

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "docker2" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "docker2" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Set up JDK 17
      uses: actions/setup-java@v4
      with:
        java-version: '17'
        distribution: 'temurin'

    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x ./gradlew
      working-directory: ${{ secrets.WORKINGDIRECTORY }}


    - name: Test with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build
      working-directory: ${{ secrets.WORKINGDIRECTORY }}



    # Configure Gradle for optimal use in GiHub Actions, including caching of downloaded dependencies.
    # See: https://github.com/gradle/actions/blob/main/setup-gradle/README.md
    - name: Setup Gradle
      uses: gradle/actions/setup-gradle@417ae3ccd767c252f5661f1ace9f835f9654f2b5 # v3.1.0

    - name: Build with Gradle Wrapper
      run: ./gradlew clean build
      working-directory: ${{ secrets.WORKINGDIRECTORY }}

    
    # - name: Build with Gradle
    #   uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@67421db6bd0bf253fb4bd25b31ebb98943c375e1
    #   working-directory: ${{ secrets.WORKINGDIRECTORY }}
    #   with:
    #     arguments: build


    # - name: Verify .jar file existence
    #   run: ls -la ./${{ secrets.WorkingDirectory }}/build/libs/


    # NOTE: The Gradle Wrapper is the default and recommended way to run Gradle (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).
    # If your project does not have the Gradle Wrapper configured, you can use the following configuration to run Gradle with a specified version.
    #
    # - name: Setup Gradle
    #   uses: gradle/actions/setup-gradle@417ae3ccd767c252f5661f1ace9f835f9654f2b5 # v3.1.0
    #   with:
    #     gradle-version: '8.5'
    #
    # - name: Build with Gradle 8.5
    #   run: ./be/tastyhub gradle build

  dependency-submission:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Set up JDK 17
      uses: actions/setup-java@v4
      with:
        java-version: '17'
        distribution: 'temurin'

    - name: docker image build
      run: docker build -t ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REPOSITORY_USERNAME }}/tastyhub .
      working-directory: ${{ secrets.WORKINGDIRECTORY }}

    - name: docker login
      uses: docker/login-action@v2
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REPOSITORY_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REPOSITORY }}

    - name: docker hub push
      run: docker push ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}/tastyhub
      working-directory: ${{ secrets.WORKINGDIRECTORY }}


this is my git action code
but when i start to dependency-submission, docker file can't find *.jar file.
this is my docker file
FROM amazoncorretto:17
LABEL authors="sky213"
ARG JAR_FILE=./build/libs/*.jar

COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","/app.jar"]

and this is our project structure
enter image description here
ah WORKINGDIRECTORY is our sturcture of back Spring
enter image description here
and this is docker image build by gitaction
can you help me to some advices?
i tried to gradle init and treat with tin of docker image part working directory and search google
but i don't found this type of error. because some people said to me about checkout logic, this is make and access build/libs and .jar file. but i used it, i don't solve this problem
